# Sharepoint Add and get reply item from message discussion board

Tags: ios, swift, sharepoint, soap

I want to add reply in particular subject in message discussion board type list  and get reply of subject from message discussion board type list by SOAP services. I am using SOAP services of SharePoint.

How to add item and get item from message discussion board?

Which type of SOAP service use for that?